# Automising the plot of more than a 100 .txt files using pandas, NaN problems

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Good afternoon

I am trying to import more than a 100 separate .txt files containing data I want to plot. I would like to automise this process, since doing the same iteration for every individual file is most tedious.

I have read up on how to read multiple .txt files, and found a nice [explanation](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/how-to-import-data-from-multiple-text-files-in-python-c3956a878fe0). However, following the example all my data gets imported as NaNs. I read up some more and found a more reliable way of importing .txt files, namely by using pd.read_fwf() as can be seen [here](http://https:/https://blog.softhints.com/python-pandas-file-dataframe/).

Although I can at least see my data now, I have no clue how to plot it, since the data is in one column separated by \t, e.g.

0 Extension (mm)\tLoad (kN)\tMachine extension (mm)\tPreload extension

1 0.000000\t\t\t

2 0.152645\t0.000059312\t.....

... etc.

I have tried using different separators in both the pd.read_csv() and pd.read_fwf() including ' ', '\t' and '-s+', but to now avail.

Of course this causes a problem, because now I can not plot my data. Speaking of, I am also not sure how to plot the data in the dataframe. I want to plot each .txt file's data separately on the same scatter plot.

I am very new to stack overflow, so pardon the format of the question if it does not conform to the normal standard. I attach my code below, but unfortunately I can not attach my .txt files. Each .txt file contains about a thousand rows of data. I attach a picture of the general format of all the files. [General format of the .txt files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMsEv.png)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp
import os
import glob

# change the working directory
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Philip de Bruin\Desktop\Universiteit van Pretoria\Nagraads\sterktetoetse_basislyn\trektoetse\speel")

# get the file names
leggername = [i for i in glob.glob("*.txt")]

# put everything in a dataframe
df = [pd.read_fwf(legger) for legger in leggername]
df
```

EDIT: the output I get now for the DataFrame is:

[     Time (s)\tLoad (kN)\tMachine Extension (mm)\tExtension  
0
1                            0.000000\t\t\t
2
3     0.152645\t0.000059312\t-...
4
...                                                 ...
997   76.0173\t0.037706\t0.005...
998
999            76.1699\t0.037709\t\t
1000
1001

```
   from  Preload  (mm)
```

0           NaN              NaN        NaN
1           NaN              NaN        NaN
2           NaN              NaN        NaN
3           NaN              NaN        NaN
4           NaN              NaN        NaN
...         ...              ...        ...
997         NaN              NaN        NaN
998         NaN              NaN        NaN
999         NaN              NaN        NaN
1000        NaN              NaN        NaN
1001        NaN              NaN        NaN

[1002 rows x 4 columns],
Time (s)\tLoad (kN)\tMachine Extension (mm)\tExtension  
0
1                            0.000000\t\t\t
2
3     0.128151\t0.000043125\t-...
4
...                                                 ...
997   63.8191\t0.034977\t-0.00...
998
999            63.9473\t0.034974\t\t
1000
1001

```
   from  Preload  (mm)
```

0           NaN              NaN        NaN
1           NaN              NaN        NaN
2           NaN              NaN        NaN
3           NaN              NaN        NaN
4           NaN              NaN        NaN
...         ...              ...        ...
997         NaN              NaN        NaN
998         NaN              NaN        NaN
999         NaN              NaN        NaN
1000        NaN              NaN        NaN
1001        NaN              NaN        NaN

[1002 rows x 4 columns],
Time (s)\tLoad (kN)\tMachine Extension (mm)\tExtension  
0
1                            0.000000\t\t\t
2
3     0.174403\t0.000061553\t0...
4
...                                                 ...
997   86.8529\t0.036093\t-0.00...
998
999   87.0273\t\t-0.0059160\t-...
1000
1001

```
   from  Preload  (mm)
```

0           NaN              NaN        NaN
1           NaN              NaN        NaN
2           NaN              NaN        NaN
3           NaN              NaN        NaN
4           NaN              NaN        NaN
...         ...              ...        ...
997         NaN              NaN        NaN
998         NaN              NaN        NaN
999         NaN              NaN        NaN
1000        NaN              NaN        NaN
1001        NaN              NaN        NaN

... etc

Comment: Upload a sample of the dataframe with messed up formatting please, I will try to help you split it [how to upload a sample df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: What is the question here? How to read multiple text files or that you have NaN values after importing the text files?

Comment: `df = [pd.read_fwf(legger) for legger in leggername]` does not result in a dataframe, but a list of dataframes. You'll need to concatenate those: `df = pd.concat([pd.read_fwf(legger) for legger in leggername])` may work (if all individual dataframes have the same structure).

Comment: For convenience, just use `leggername = glob.glob("*.txt")` instead of `leggername = [i for i in glob.glob("*.txt")]`. The list comprehension is basically redundant.

Comment: @PatrykKowalski, here is the output I get.

Comment: Can you ignore the first row with the `0.00000` value? That would make things a lot easier.

Comment: "I want to plot each .txt file's data separately on the same scatter plot.": *how* separately? Different symbol, color, or just all the same (in which case there isn't much "separately")?

Comment: @Mr.T My question is how to get rid of the \t between the correctly read .txt files, as well as the NaNs in the incorrectly .txt files, and then how to plot the data when read correctly.

Comment: You've just made your question unreadable, with all the output.

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for the suggestions, your first suggestion puts everything in one dataframe, which I believe will assist a lot in plotting. As for deleting a few rows: no problem, there is enough data so that all the necessary information is still available.

Comment: Ok, then your problem might be easily solved. I would think the very first data row (with the single 0.0000) would be important to keep, but if it can be ignored, all the easier.

Comment: @9769953 I want to plot them separately in different colours as well as symbols. The graphs will be used for a thesis, so the different samples should be distinguishable when printed in black and white. I do realise that this will probably limit the amount of samples I have on the same graph, but once the code is sorted I can play around with that.

Comment: If you have a 100 files, there will not be enough distinct colors or symbols to see the separate samples in a single plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic gist is to skip the first data row (that has a single value in it), then read the individual files with `pd.read_csv`, using tab as the separator, and stack them together.

There is, however, a  more problematic issue: the data files turn out to be UTF-16 encoded (the binary data show a NUL character at the even positions), *but* there is no byte-order-mark (BOM) to indicate this. As a result, you can't specify the encoding in `read_csv`, but have to manually read each file as binary, then decode it with UTF-16 to a string, then feed that string to `read_csv`. Since the latter requires a filename or IO-stream, the text data needs to be put into a `StringIO` object first (or save the corrected data to disk first, then read the corrected file; might not be a bad idea).

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import io

# change the working directory
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Philip de Bruin\Desktop\Universiteit van Pretoria\Nagraads\sterktetoetse_basislyn\trektoetse\speel")

dfs = []
for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        data = fp.read()  # a single file should fit in memory just fine
    # Decode the UTF-16 data that is missing a BOM
    string = data.decode('UTF-16')
    # And put it into a stream, for ease-of-use with `read_csv`
    stream = io.StringIO(string) 

    # Read the data from the, now properly decoded, stream
    # Skip the single-value row, and use tabs as separators
    df = pd.read_csv(stream, sep='\t', skiprows=[1])

    # To keep track of the individual files, add an "origin" column
    # with its value set to the corresponding filename
    df['origin'] = filename
    dfs.append(df)

# Concate all dataframes (default is to stack the rows)
df = pd.concat(dfs)


# For a quick and dirty plot, you can enjoy the power of Seaborn
import seaborn as sns
# Use appropriate (full) column names, and use the 'origin' 
# column for the hue and symbol
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='Time (s)', y='Machine Extension (mm)', hue='origin', style='origin')
```

[image: Scatterplot result: machine extension vs time]

[Seaborn's scatterplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html).

Comment: I get everything NaN now, although the dataframe looks much more ordered.  Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ...
995 NaN NaN NaN NaN
996 NaN NaN NaN NaN
997 NaN NaN NaN NaN
998 NaN NaN NaN NaN
999 NaN NaN NaN NaN
8800 rows × 4 columns

Comment: Yes, sorry, the '\t' comment was a copying error

Comment: I looked at your P1T01 example file, and with the above code, you shouldn't get NaNs. Try with `glob.glob("P1T01.txt")` (or whatever the file is called exactly) first; the error might be caused by another, incompatible file.

Comment: I still get the same, only now the rows are down to 1000, which is the same as the amount of rows in the .txt file.

Comment: Is there any way you can (and are allowed to) make a few of those input text files available to play around with? There's probably something about the files that we can't see that's causing the NaNs.

Comment: @PhilipdeBruin If you have a GitHub or GitLab account, that is one possible place. Dropbox might be another one. Depending on the size, you could copy-paste an entire file into a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) anonymously. There are probably a few others like that.

Comment: Yes, of course. I can not find a way to upload it to Stack Overflow, so here is a link to the folder on my Google Drive. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19C-kyW5Ei8PBQ6ozw3IRuWz8D7kxnwgB?usp=sharing

Comment: @PhilipdeBruin I think I've found the issue (and solved it), but to verify that Google didn't mess up the files: could you copy-paste the output of `print(open('P1T01.txt', 'rb').read()[:8])` in a comment below? (If you're running Python from a command line, you could just do `python -c "print(open('P1T01.txt', 'rb').read()[:8])"`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. If I print the first command in Jupyter Notebook, I get the following output: b'T\x00i\x00m\x00e\x00'

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I'm getting, and what I think is the issue (mainly) behind your problem with the NaNs.

Comment: @PhilipdeBruin See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would never figure that out on my own, it works like a charm!

Comment: It is a weird and unexpected thing, so it's no wonder you got stumped. You should really check how you get your input data files; it would appear some software that writes or processes these files is faulty. Perhaps there is a configuration option in a piece of software that ensures the output is UTF-8 instead of (malformed) UTF-16 (UTF-8 is generally considered better), which may save headaches and debugging time in the future. (Unless, of course, this is just a one-off, caused in some weird, unreproducible, way.)

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. I suspect that the computer connected to the machine doing the tests are at fault, it is both an old machine and old computer.